# Driving licence and vehicle registration in EU without adress

Tags: driving, vehicle

Are there any countries in EU+EFTA, which allow to hold their driving licence and registering a vehicle without having a fixed address? In many countries the address is shown as a field on the licence and I am trying to determine, if it's possible to obtain it without having to update addresses on move, when there is no fixed abode. The same goes for registration plates.

Answer (score 1):

The address field on an EU driving licence is optional - not every Member State will implement it. Indeed, it looks like only the UK, Ireland, and Poland currently display Field 8 (Address) on the driving licence photocard.

However, most Member States still require you to submit an address when applying for your driving licence and when registering a vehicle. It appears this is so you can actually receive the driving licence/vehicle registration certificate through the post, and so they can contact you if necessary (e.g. a court summons).

The same licence is issued by Iceland, Lichtenstein, and Norway as part of EFTA and they don't seem to put the address field on the licence either--although I cannot determine if they require the address when registering the licence/vehicle respectively.